# How do I change button name onselect?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I want to add `name="question"` to the selected radio button. (And remove it if the user selects the other). How can I do it?

```
<input type="radio" value="female" />Female

<input type="radio" value="male" />Male
```

Thanks

Comment: Why? Only the checked radio button will be a successful control (and thus submitted to the server) anyway (and if they don't have the same name, they won't act as a group).

Comment: Why did you delete your first question? You should find out why your WordPress widget isn't getting the right value, rather than going through such hacky lengths.

Comment: I need to do it because the plugin can't handle having two inputs with the same name and I prefer an external solution than hacking the plugin since it get's regular updates and it would only mean trouble to modify it.

Comment: I deleted it because someone told me what I should do and now I want to know how! Thanks

Comment: If the plugin doesn't handle your use case, modify it, find another plugin, or write your own.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Answer and Questions but I need some functions like moderation. And if it wasn't for this it would be working perfectly why change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check out jquery

http://api.jquery.com/attr/
http://api.jquery.com/css/

```
$("input[type='radio']").change( function() {
    $(this).css('display' 'hidden');
    $(this).attr('name', 'question');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id for each of your radio, then add method in javascript which will append clicked element with attribute name="question" and remove attribute name from another radio button.

But if you are trying to submit only value which is selected than you don't have to worry, add a name="question" to both of them and only one which is selected is going to be submitted. And you can get it in your php like $_POST["question"]

But if you are using ajax to send data to php then you can also access value of item by using FormName.question.

I hope this helps

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do but I still have no idea how. I'll do a little investigation on how to do it thanks anyway.